# How can I change dropdown text on ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

I have a helpers/config.js

```
Accounts.ui.config({

});
```

After playing around with this for a couple hours and searching I've been unable to find a way to change the tex SIGNIN/JOIN that is generated in the top bootstrap nav.

How do I do it the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package is using `anti:i18n` as seen in :

https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/blob/master/package.js#L15

So what you can do is simply override the default i18n strings declared there :

https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/blob/master/i18n/en.i18n.js#L25

I never used `anti:i18n` but I think throwing this code in your app should do the trick :

```
i18n.map("en",{
  loginButtonsLoggedOutDropdown: {
    signIn: "YOUR SIGN IN TEXT",
    up: "YOUR JOIN TEXT"
  }
});
```

You also need to add the package to your app using this command :

```
meteor add anti:i18n
```

That's because even if the package is a dependency of `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`, you are not allowed to access it in your app, you must explicitly list it as a dependency of your app.

Comment: After installing the package  'meteor add anti:i18n' I placed your code in my config.js and it worked as expected.

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the '/' if I just want this to be a login and not a register?